# Speed of civilization change

Tags: magic, government, technological-development, civilization, cities

Imagine one to three persons going back in time to a society like that of the Roman Kingdom (the period before the Republic), and they attempt to reform as well as modernize to an extent (up to the technology of the late 17th Century), but improve hygiene and sanitation to the same amount as the late 20th. Would this be possible in at least 100 years? Let's say the individuals are highly educated in many fields and most of the time will be spent on technological improvements and hygiene and not so much on things such as criminal justice. Let us also assume that the territory has all the resources required and has a population of two million. And they also easily manage to gain control of the kingdom within 10 years and there may also be magic. Would this idea be feasible to be carried out if there was a proper plan?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, Inquisitor, but please be aware. Questions like yours are dime a dozen on this site. And they're all wrong. Do the research & look up those questions. The 'magic' of being from the future won't change the past significantly. It requires the resources & manpower of a colonizing empire.

Comment: Welcome. I'll add that there exists a story with somewhat similar premise, Chinese webnovel named Release That Witch. You might want to try getting some inspiration there.

Comment: @a4andriod I have stated that the resources required are all abundant and a manpower of 2 million( and reproducing) in the statement. Could you at least explain why it is wrong in order to help improve instead of simply telling me to search it up myself.  If I was going to research myself then what is the point of this website?

Comment: The point of this website is usually to either get answer to a simple question, or get pointed in general direction for what you should research, if the question is more complex.

Comment: Alright then, by the way I'll be looking into _Release that Witch_.

Comment: This questions or a variation of it has been asked a couple of times on this stack exchange already. This is not feasible, but it may be believable if you are good at world building. A couple of people that apparently have to do a lot of work will hardly have the time to define several disease outbreak protocols.  A doctor is a very highly specalized individual that has recieved years of training with very advanced equipment. Those are just two examples to show you how insanely complex all of this is. The Romans were far from stupid, a couple of people can't elevate them - things take time

Comment: What is the "Roman Kingdom"? (The point being that most of the time in its very long history Rome was not ruled by kings.) The [regal period of ancient Rome](/home/alexp/.mozilla/firefox/x82iouqg.default-release/lock), from the 8th to the 6th century before the common era? The time in the Middle Ages when the emperor-elect of the Holy Roman Empire was called [King of the Romans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_the_Romans). although he most usually didn't even rule Rome? The time in Italian history, late 19th to mid-20th century, when the country was a kingdom and its capital was Rome?

Comment: Yes the regal period

Comment: "Regal period:" Well, in those days Rome was a very small city, quite poor, with a very small territory, ruled by a foreign (= Etruscan) elite, and it definitely did not have the economic base to do any kind of technological improvements.

Comment: You need the manpower & resources of a colonizing empire to take control of the Roman kingdom in the first place. This cannot be done by sending a few highly select individuals into the past. The reason I suggested doing your researah is this type of question has been asked too many times already. You can use this site to find out the answer.

Comment: The granddady of propositions of a person going into the past & changing it is L Sprague de Camp's novel *Lest Darkness Fall*. A timeslipped archaeologist prevents the Fall of Rome by introducing certain improvements. That's a pleasant fiction, if you consider what it would really take, then you need a time-travelling East India Company to do it.

Comment: If your question could have been improved with a few suggestions, I would have doee so. Alas, questions like yours  been asked & answered many times before, usually in the negative, that pointing out you can use this site to find out the answer(s), because they're here to find, is the logical way to improve your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could a time-traveler change a medieval society if he can prepare and bring something from our time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54776/how-could-a-time-traveler-change-a-medieval-society-if-he-can-prepare-and-bring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technological reform without social reform can be less than successful.**

You know why we call plumbing by that name? The word literally comes from the Latin for Lead; they used the metal for their water management throughout the empire because it was cheap, malleable and easy to manage as a resource. There is some evidence available to say that the Romans actually knew lead was toxic, but they still used it because it was too (in a word) useful to give up.

Arguably, we could say the same in the modern world about single use plastic shopping bags. In Australia, we've just recently had one of our last states ban their use. Shopping bags have been touted as the cause of much pollution in the ocean and have been seen as a massive impost on consumption of petroleum products for their manufacture. These have been known issues for decades, but it isn't until there is a compelling drive at the social level to change that we see action on these things.

The same will be true if your time travelers come back with technology alone. Taking gunpowder back to Roman times may well be a game changer and it is the sort of thing they may embrace, because their legions were always looking for advantages in combat and it was a big focus of Roman life that their army was (more or less) unstoppable. But, did they really see healthcare or hygiene as a priority? Well, they were still using toxic metals to route their water supply, so probably not.

What will make your empire grow, what will really improve the lives of its citizens, is education. Sure, put gunpowder out there as a gesture of goodwill and get your name established as someone of influence, then use that influence to redirect education into STEM research as well as the humanities. Building these two *in concert* allows you to change community sentiment to best take advantage of the technology devised through STEM research, and it also means that removing lead from Rome and other large cities in the empire could be justified as an expense when the people demand it as they understand the cost to them personally and to their empire.

Ultimately, what I'm saying is that the only way the introduction of technology allows an empire to grow is if they're ready for the change that such a technology can support and actually want it. Otherwise, introducing technology blindly means it is likely only going to be used in a destructive way because that allows for those with that technology to have an easy or cheap capability of building power over others. To use a technology for good, a society must be able to see the need for a more inclusive set of goals that extend past selfish desires. That requires far more than technological advancement; it requires social advancement.

The answer to your question therefore is yes; it's *possible* but only if your focus is social change, and you are careful to only introduce new technologies as the society you're building is ready for them. I have no figures on how hard it is to change the mindset of an ancient Roman (having never tried it before) so I have no idea how much of an effort this would be but my focus would start not with the senate, but with the mob. Get them demanding reforms as a groundswell base in Rome itself and you might be surprised at how quickly things change.

Comment: Lead is not dangerous for most of the applications where it was used by Romans. Cold water lead pipes are not dangerous, and evacuation lead pipes are not dangerous. (And, surprise, the Romans did not use lead for hot water pipes...) But, yes, they did use lead in some dangerous applications, although those were not common or generally approved. Anyway, the question was clarified to be asking about the regal period in the history of ancient Rome; and in those days Rome was small, poor, and subject to foreign domination, so its chances of developing any interesting technology are tiny.